# Bootstrap 4 Grids

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

```
<div class="col-8">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="img.jpg">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

В данный момент этот кусок выходит так

[image: Пример 1]

Как сделать чтоб он выходил так

[image: Пример 2]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style type="text/css">
            .bigBlock{
                border:1px solid black;
                height: 200px
            }
            .block{
                border:1px solid black;
                height: 100px
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 bigBlock">
                block1
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 block">
                        block2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 block">
                        block3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 block">
                block4
            </div>
             <div class="col-4 block">
                block5
            </div>
             <div class="col-4 block">
                block6
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]